# Asterisk Java AGI: utils.c write() returned error: Broken pipe

Tags: java, asterisk, agi

I have written a hello world Asterisk AGI script using Java. The script runs as expected and plays the hello world sound file, but the asterisk console is giving an error though:

> ERROR[31058]: utils.c:1164 ast_carefulwrite: write() returned error: Broken pipe

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using asterisk-java-0.3.1.jar and Asterisk 1.8.10.1~dfsg-1ubuntu1

Java class as below:

```java
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiException;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiRequest;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.BaseAgiScript;

public class AgiHelloWorld extends BaseAgiScript 
{
    @Override
    public void service(AgiRequest arg0, AgiChannel arg1) throws AgiException 
    {
        answer();
        streamFile("hello-world");
        hangup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs when Asterisk tries to write some line to your AGI/FastAGI after script finish execution.

Usually, asterisk send headers, and then waits for commands. After each command asterisk sends a response. But here is one exception, at the and it writes on more line

```
HANGUP
```

I think it is the line asterisk can`t write in your case. You can check it by turning on agi debug. Write in the console:

```
agi set debug on
```

and then after running your script you should see something like this:

```
    -- <SIP/XXXX-0000007c>AGI Script YOUR_AGI_NAME completed, returning 4
<SIP/XXXX-0000007c>AGI Tx >> HANGUP
ERROR[1502]: utils.c:1232 ast_carefulwrite: write() returned error: Broken pipe
```

You can see that asterisk try to send HANGUP after script completed. You don`t have to worry about it, but it is a library bug.

Comment: Yes! Thats the case. Asterisk generates a result message for every command send in and expects this to be handled by the agi script. If the script didn't read the returned result asterisk throws the ERROR above.

Answer (score -3):

This is error is generally occurred when you don’t have access permission, Please log in as the root user and try you will be successful.